# How to update a state of array type in useEffect in a for-each loop to continously add values to the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, use-effect

(I'll admit it) this question is quite confusing so I'll provide some example code below haha:

```
const [list, setList] = useState([])

*functional component methods go here*

useEffect(() => {
   arr1.forEach((item) => {                 //in a for-each loop
      db.collection('coll1').where('field', '==', item).onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        var el = snapshot.docs
        el = el.map(doc =>({
                        id: doc.id,
                        post: doc.data()
                    }))
        setList(now => now.concat(el))     //but this only does 1 iteration of the for-each loop
      })
   }
}, [])
```

As you can see I am trying to add document data to my state through my for-each loop for every "item".
The problem is that this only goes through the for-each loop once.

I cannot use variables to save data in my for-each loop as it is not possible to save data in variables in a firebase reference.

Please advise. Thanks. Let me know if more clarification is required!

Comment: Do you want to store each value of array in your state?

Comment: what do you mean by it only runs once? have you determined that since only the last item is only ever added to the state?

Comment: @SanatGupta in my for-each loop, I would like to store each 'el' per iteration in my state, so that my state will have all the 'el's in the end.

Comment: best to create a new array using map instead of forEach, concatenate and spread the resultant array with the previous state after completing the map. `setList(now => [...now.concat(mappedArray)])` or `setList(now => [...now, ...mappedArray])`

Comment: @Gandzal I have console logged my state later in my code and it seems to only record one iteration of the for-each loop. (i.e. it is not iteratively collecting all 'el's from each run-through of the loop)

Comment: I think its because setList is async, so now is always your initial state, not what you are expecting. call the setList method outside of the loop. using `const mappedArray = arr1.map(() => {});`

Comment: @Gandzal that explanation makes sense... I'll try it out tomorrow and get back to you. Appreciate it.

Comment: no problem. I hope you manage. Let us know